# W/System: A resource failed to call close

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app keeps crashing in the AndroidStudios emulator with "A resource failed to call close". The following code is what is causing the issue but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        ArrayList<CategoryModel> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(new CategoryModel("","History",""));
        
        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categories);
        binding.categoryList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        binding.categoryList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Here is the CategoryAdapter code:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.categoryModels = categoryModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_category, null);
        return new CategoryViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CategoryModel model = categoryModels.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(model.getCategoryName());
    }
}
```

Comment: can see your `CategoryAdapter`'s code. Add it to your question.

Comment: add complete crash details

Comment: @MDev added a portion of CategoryAdapter.java